# How to get an array of unique values from an array containing duplicates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

Given a `['0','1','1','2','3','3','3']` array, the result should be `['0','1','2','3']`.

Comment: Yeah dude jquery solves all problems.

Comment: You can use a utility library like underscore.js http://underscorejs.org/#uniq for these "easy" operations

Comment: Oh, the irony of a duplicate question.

Comment: @LucioPaiva where's the array of duplicate questions??? 

Answer (score 257):

Edited

ES6 solution:

```
[...new Set(a)];
```

Alternative:

```
Array.from(new Set(a));
```

Old response. O(n^2) (do not use it with large arrays!)

```
var arrayUnique = function(a) {
    return a.reduce(function(p, c) {
        if (p.indexOf(c) < 0) p.push(c);
        return p;
    }, []);
};
```

Comment: Nonsense! You DO need to use semicolons! http://jsfiddle.net/bTNc2/

Comment: Douglas Crockford would be having fits @countfloortiles. You need semicolons.

Comment: It's 2014 now, so we need semicolons again.

Comment: @PedroL. "You need semicolons if you want to minify your code?" Why do you say that? Omitting semicolons is a way of minifying your code. A semicolon character takes just as much space as a newline character. Replacing all your newlines with semicolons will not give you smaller code. But the process of "minifying" it will become yet another point of potential failure, and your end result will be obfuscated code that is difficult to debug.

Comment: @PedroL. Just want to mention that this function is case-sensitive, so you still could have duplicates. `c = c.toString().toLowerCase();` solved this for me.

Comment: using `p.indexOf(c) == -1` is better?
and I vote for this cool solution!

Comment: If you understand how semicolons work in Javascript, using them is a matter of style. If you don't, they'll confuse you no matter what you do. Here's a good write-up: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

To minify Javascript correctly, you need a full parser anyway, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It's 2015 now, so we don't need semicolons again.

Comment: This is where you are wrong @MarkKnol. It is now April, and everyone knows that semicolons are required in the Spring and Summer of the Northern Hemisphere. Granted your comment was written in Feb, so I suppose you should be granted some leeway. By the way, can someone come back in Autumn (Fall for y'all) and remove the semi-colons?

Comment: Can this function be a prototype?

Comment: Will we need to use semicolons in 2016?

Comment: It's an even year, so yes, you do need semicolons :)

Comment: this has O(n^2) performance and is therefore undesirable for large arrays. the same work can be done in O(n) time as shown by some of the other solutions below, which use hashing.

Comment: The solution above is O(n).... `indexOf` doesn't look up the array. It knows exactly where the value is stored it's a O(1) operation.

Comment: It is midway through 2016 now, and for the most part it's been a `semicolons are optional but highly encouraged` year.

Comment: With good minifiers, you don't need semicolons, as they will take care of that for you. We code in ES6 ([babel](https://babeljs.io/)) and use (almost) no semicolons and our production environment is fully minified.

Comment: It's 2016 now, we need semicolons again

Comment: It's 2042 here, what are semicolons ?

Comment: So. It's 2017 now. Year of the Fire Rooster Ding You. Semicolons or not?

Comment: @MangledDeutz Full colons now.

Comment: @MangledDeutz in 2017 [this happened](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176114).

Comment: It's now 2017, and according to [**StandardJS**](https://standardjs.com/#the-rules), we should **not** use semicolons. They cite [**these**](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding) [**three**](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) [**references**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsfbh17Ax9I) for their reasoning.

Comment: It's now 2018.  We have decided no matter which semicolon standard you use, whoever takes over your project will explain convincingly that the previous dev was an idiot for choosing that standard.

Comment: It's 2018 and now TC39 recommends using semicolons to avoid hazards of ASI - https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1062

Comment: It's the year 3000, use mixed semicolons, either alternate or use semicolons on even lines. If you add new lines to your code you will need to refactor all lines so that they continue to follow the first rule.

Comment: @jack I bow to you for sparking a brilliant comment thread on this post! 

Comment: It's now 2018. I give up JavaScript.

Comment: 2019; still a mixed bag, developers [continue to use spaces instead of tabs for indentation without regard for global warming](https://peterbraden.co.uk/article/space-infidel/).

Answer (score 52):

If you want to maintain order:

```
arr = arr.reverse().filter(function (e, i, arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(e, i+1) === -1;
}).reverse();
```

Since there's no built-in reverse indexof, I reverse the array, filter out duplicates, then re-reverse it.

The filter function looks for any occurence of the element after the current index (before in the original array). If one is found, it throws out this element.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you could use lastindexOf (if you don't care about order):

```
arr = arr.filter(function (e, i, arr) {
    return arr.lastIndexOf(e) === i;
});
```

This will keep unique elements, but only the last occurrence. This means that ['0', '1', '0'] becomes ['1', '0'], not ['0', '1'].

Comment: Interesting solution, does lastIndexOf work?

Comment: Kind of, but it depends on what you mean by that. You could use it if you didn't need order instead of the reverse() hack.

Comment: +1 for golfing. Unfortunately the straight `for` loop  seems to perform better [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/distinct-hash-vs-comparison).  Damn function calls are so expensive.

Comment: @merv - The OP said nothing about performance, so I got creative. Code's simple enough, no?

Comment: Yep, I'd definitely prefer writing your way!

Comment: Nice! I like `[1,2,3,1,1].filter(function(elem,idx,arr){ return arr.indexOf(elem) >= idx; });` better though, it's more straightforward

Comment: Brilliant, @tjameson!

Comment: Awesome @BenjaminGruenbaum that seems the most intuitive!

Comment: here's a minified prototype of it : Array.prototype.unique=function(){return this.reverse().filter(function(e,i,array){return array.indexOf(e, i+1)===-1;}).reverse();}

Comment: There _is no_ maintaining order, as can be seen by the comments on the top answer.

Answer (score 26):

Here is an Array Prototype function:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var unique = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (unique.indexOf(this[i]) == -1) {
            unique.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return unique;
};
```

Comment: This is the easiest reading code XD

Answer (score 14):

With [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)

```
_.uniq([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]); //=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Would this work for array of arrays

Answer (score 13):

It's 2014 now guys, and time complexity still matters!

```js
array.filter(function() {
  var seen = {};
  return function(element, index, array) {
    return !(element in seen) && (seen[element] = 1);
  };
}());
```

http://jsperf.com/array-filter-unique/13

Answer (score 9):

```
function array_unique(arr) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (result.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) {
            result.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Not a built in function. If the product list does not contain the item, add it to unique list and return unique list.

Comment: Might want to mention that this won't work in IE8 or below..

Comment: Why would it not work in IE8?

Comment: Perhaps because there's a closing parenthesis missing, it should be:
result.push(arr[i]);

Answer (score 6):

There you go! You are welcome!

```
Array.prototype.unique = function()
{
    var tmp = {}, out = [];
    for(var i = 0, n = this.length; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if(!tmp[this[i]]) { tmp[this[i]] = true; out.push(this[i]); }
    }
    return out;
}

var a = [1,2,2,7,4,1,'a',0,6,9,'a'];
var b = a.unique();
alert(a);
alert(b);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find all kinds of array unique implementations here:

http://jsperf.com/distinct-hash-vs-comparison/12

http://jsperf.com/array-unique-functional

I prefer functional styles such as:

```
var arr = ['lol', 1, 'fdgdfg', 'lol', 'dfgfg', 'car', 1, 'car', 'a', 'blah', 'b', 'c', 'd', '0', '1', '1', '2', '3', '3', '3', 'crazy', 'moot', 'car', 'lol', 1, 'fdgdfg', 'lol', 'dfgfg', 'car', 1, 'car', 'a', 'blah', 'b', 'c', 'd', '0', '1', '1', '2', '3', '3', '3', 'crazy', 'moot', 'car', 'lol', 1, 'fdgdfg'];

var newarr = arr.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
    //console.log(prev, cur);
    if (prev.indexOf(cur) < 0) prev.push(cur);
    return prev;
}, []);

var secarr = arr.filter(function(element, index, array){
    //console.log(element, array.indexOf(element), index);
    return array.indexOf(element) >= index;
});

//reverses the order
var thirdarr = arr.filter(function (e, i, arr) {
    //console.log(e, arr.lastIndexOf(e), i);
    return arr.lastIndexOf(e) === i;
});

console.log(newarr);
console.log(secarr);
console.log(thirdarr);
```

Comment: I think most of the solutions proposed have a potential problem in that they are computation intensive.  They will need O(n^2) operation at least (due to calling indexOf for each iteration).  So when using a small array it is nice but not for large arrays.  I am making this comment here as there is a link to a performance test and I think it is misleading due to data which is too small.

Comment: and here is a better performance study: http://www.shamasis.net/2009/09/fast-algorithm-to-find-unique-items-in-javascript-array/

Comment: @terrinecold terrific, you should post up an answer referencing that. Would be great if the javascript compiler/interpreter automatically optimised it.

Comment: @terrinecold wait, the method posted in your link is the same one in the comparisons that I linked to, and it isn't always faster. I suppose it might be for larger arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_unique(nav_array) {
    nav_array = nav_array.sort(function (a, b) { return a*1 - b*1; });      
    var ret = [nav_array[0]];       
    // Start loop at 1 as element 0 can never be a duplicate
    for (var i = 1; i < nav_array.length; i++) { 
        if (nav_array[i-1] !== nav_array[i]) {              
            ret.push(nav_array[i]);             
        }       
    }
    return ret;     
}
```

Comment: Not a good implementation for something called `array_unique` because you rely on it being an numeric value. Even for a number-array-unique, I think parseInt would be better way to go (I could be wrong)

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Try it.

```
function getUnique(a) {
  var b = [a[0]], i, j, tmp;
  for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    tmp = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
      if (a[i] == b[j]) {
        tmp = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (tmp) {
      b.push(a[i]);
    }
  }
  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No redundant "return" array, no ECMA5 (I'm pretty sure!) and simple to read.

```
function removeDuplicates(target_array) {
    target_array.sort();
    var i = 0;

    while(i < target_array.length) {
        if(target_array[i] === target_array[i+1]) {
            target_array.splice(i+1,1);
        }
        else {
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    return target_array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use this. There is nothing wrong with using the for loop, I just like using the build-in functions. You could even pass in a boolean argument for typecast or non typecast matching, which in that case you would use a for loop (the `filter()` method/function does typecast matching (===))

```
Array.prototype.unique =
function()
{
    return this.filter(
        function(val, i, arr)
        {
            return (i <= arr.indexOf(val));
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way you can do remove duplicate values from the **Array.**

```
function ArrNoDupe(dupArray) {
   var temp = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < dupArray.length; i++) {
         temp[dupArray[i]] = true;
         var uniqueArray = [];
       for (var k in temp)
           uniqueArray.push(k);
 return uniqueArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use an object for initial storage of the array information.  Then convert back.  For example:

```
var arr = ['0','1','1','2','3','3','3'];
var obj = {};

for(var i in arr) 
    obj[i] = true;

arr = [];
for(var i in obj) 
    arr.push(i);
```

Variable "arr" now contains ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

Comment: Of course, this would only work for strings.

Comment: …and the result should not contain the property names of the initial array, but the actual items. Expected: `['0', '1', '2', '3']`

Answer (score 0):

Those of you who work with google closure library, have at their disposal `goog.array.removeDuplicates`, which is the same as unique. It changes the array itself, though.

Answer (score -2):

```
    //
    Array.prototype.unique =
    ( function ( _where ) {
      return function () {
        for (
          var
          i1 = 0,
          dups;
          i1 < this.length;
          i1++
        ) {
          if ( ( dups = _where( this, this[i1] ) ).length > 1 ) {
            for (
              var
              i2 = dups.length;
              --i2;
              this.splice( dups[i2], 1 )
            );
          }
        }
        return this;
      }
    } )(
      function ( arr, elem ) {
        var locs  = [];
        var tmpi  = arr.indexOf( elem, 0 );
        while (
          ( tmpi ^ -1 )
          && (
            locs.push( tmpi ),
            tmpi = arr.indexOf( elem, tmpi + 1 ), 1
          )
        );
        return locs;
      }
    );
    //
```

Answer (score -4):

```
Array.prototype.unique =function(){
    var uniqObj={};
    for(var i=0;i< this.length;i++){
      uniqObj[this[i]]=this[i]; 
    }
    return uniqObj;
}
```

Comment: If you tested this out, or even gave an example of a test, you would have seen that this returns an object and not the desired output the user asked for. Please test your code next time.