# Couchbase - return distinct values

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I have a list of small JSON documents in the format:

```
{
 "name":"Kate",
 "event":"read"
},
{
 "name":"Jon",
 "event":"delete"
},...
```

My map function is this:

```
function(doc, meta){
  emit(doc.event, null);
}
```

As a result I get a list of all events, including duplicates. How do I reduce the resultset to distinct values only?

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177986/writing-reduce-function-in-couchbase

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it with a name like that :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer from the other question, modified to suit this question. I hope this helps someone! The reduce function:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  return keys.filter(function (e, i, arr) {
    return arr.lastIndexOf(e) === i;
  });
}
```

Comment: if you do this you could encounter an error solved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152576/error-reducer-when-attempting-to-do-distinct-reduce