# error (Reducer: ) when attempting to do distinct reduce

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I am getting an error when trying to do a DISTINCT reduce that I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348525/couchbase-return-distinct-values). I have reproduced this error on the beer-sample bucket, so this should be easy to reproduce. I have not seen any errors in the `mapreduce_errors.txt` file, or anything that would lead me anywhere in the others. (If you would like me to search or post snippets of other files, please ask).

Running couchbase enterprise 4 beta, on Windows 2008 R2 (This also happened on the 3.0.1 community edition as well.).

Here is my map function (Using the beer-sample bucket, that ships directly with couchbase).

```
function(doc, meta) {
  switch(doc.type) {
  case "brewery":
    emit(meta.id);
    break;
  }
}
```

Here is my reduce function:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  return keys.filter(function (e, i, arr) {
    return arr.lastIndexOf(e) === i;
  });
}
```

This is the error:

> reason: error (Reducer: )

Also an imgur of the view page if it helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qpZ5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within your custom reduce function: **you're not handling the case when it's being called as part of a re-reduce.**

As per [Couchbase documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-writing.html):

> The base format of the reduce() function is as follows:
>
> ```
> function(key, values, rereduce) {
>     ...
>     return retval;
> }
> ```
>
> The reduce function is supplied three arguments:
>
> `key`: The key is the unique key derived from the map() function and the
>   group_level parameter.
>
> `values`: The values argument is an array of all of the values that match
>   a particular key. For example, if the same key is output three times,
>   data will be an array of three items containing, with each item
>   containing the value output by the emit() function.
>
> `rereduce`: The rereduce indicates whether the function is being called
>   as part of a re-reduce, that is, the reduce function being called
>   again to further reduce the input data.
>
> When `rereduce` is false:
>
> - The supplied `key` argument will be an array where the first argument is the   `key` as emitted by the map function, and the `id` is the document ID that   generated the key.
> - The values is an array of values where each element of the array matches the   corresponding element within the array of `keys`.
>
> When `rereduce` is true:
>
> - **`key` will be null.**
> - `values` will be an array of values as returned by a previous `reduce()`   function. The function should return the reduced version
>     of the information by calling the return() function. The format of the
>     return value should match the format required for the specified key.

Bold formatting is mine, and the highlighted words are quite important: you should consider that sometimes, you'll receive the `keys` argument with a value of `null`.

According to the docs, you should handle the case when `rereduce` is `true` within your `reduce()` function, and you should know that in this case, `keys` will be `null`. In the case of your `reduce()` function, you could do something like this:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  if (rereduce) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var distinct = values[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < distinct.length; j++) {
        result.push(distinct[j]);
      }
    }
    return result.filter(function (e, i, arr) {
      return arr.lastIndexOf(e) === i;
    });
  }

  return keys.filter(function (e, i, arr) {
    return arr.lastIndexOf(e) === i;
  });
}
```

Here, I'm firstly handling the re-reduce phase. For this I'm flattening the array of arrays that I'm receiving in the `values` argument and then I'm removing the duplicates that might have appeared after the merge.

Then it comes your original code, which returns the `keys` argument array without duplicates.

To test that this `reduce()` function actually works, I've used the following `map()` function:

```
function(doc, meta) {
  switch(doc.type) {
  case "brewery":
    emit(meta.id, null);
    emit(meta.id, null);
    break;
  }
}
```

This intentionally generates duplicates, which then are removed by the `reduce()` function.

Comment: [This made zero change](http://i.imgur.com/umLy8mE.png). Suffice it to say, I've tried emitting `meta.id` as the key and the value; null and the document as both the key/value, and combinations of both, as well as modifying the reduce function to work with the key/value. All have resulted in the same error.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, this error occurred in the 3.0.1 community edition as well.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/EnSetMe.png) is the output I'm getting now (I'm using my bucket now). I'm now getting duplicates in [my reduce function](http://i.imgur.com/NrRhQ6u.png).

Comment: @FrankerZ There was a mistake in my reduction function. I've edited my answer. Please try now.

Comment: Is there any logging in the reduce or map functions? Something like a `console.log` in javascript which would output to a file somewhere, so I can see how the function is working to reduce?

Comment: @FrankerZ I really don't know. When I work with couchbase, I use the view results as my log ;)

Comment: Well, you've earned the checkmark, and the bounty. If you end up finding out if there is logging functionality, can you post back? I'm really curious now...

Comment: @FrankerZ Sure, if I find out how to log, I'll post it here.

Comment: @FrankerZ Couchbase forum circa 2015: `Call log("...") to log a message from a map function.`
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/what-is-a-good-approach-for-debugging-errors-in-views/4528/2

Answer (score 0):

While this reduce works as a development view, it does not as a production view. The dataset must be too large so you have to implement the rereduce. This documentation should help http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-writing.html#reduce-functions

Comment: This doesn't work in either, and I'm using the sample dataset. It can'tbe that large can it?

Comment: The dev views are supposed to be ran against a small dataset, so I