# Populate input with unique array of selected checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox, unique

I'd like to populate an input with the comma seperated values of selected checkboxes and exclude duplicates.

The code below works but I don't know how to get the duplicates out.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="" id="tags">

    <input type="checkbox" value="apple"><label>apple</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="banana"><label>banana</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="melon"><label>melon</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="melon"><label>melon</label>

</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {

    var vals = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');

    $('#tags').val(vals);

});​
```

Comment: Keep an array of the mapped values and check with an if statement?

Comment: This should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486479/javascript-array-unique