# Duplicate values removal using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, duplicates

```
var arr1=["a","b","b","c","c","d"];
var arr2=["b","c",];
```

arr1 has duplicate values which are listed in arr2.
Now I want to remove the duplicate values from arr1 using arr2. Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486479/javascript-array-unique

Comment: Visit this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930516/compare-two-javascript-arrays-and-remove-duplicates

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Array's `.filter()` method.

```
arr1 = arr1.filter(function (val) {
    return arr2.indexOf(val) === -1;
});
```

---

For IE8 or earlier, this code should work:

```
arr1 = arr1.filter(function (val) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i += 1) {
        if ( val === arr2[i] ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Property or Method indexOf is undefined...

Comment: Works fine for me on `Firefox 23.0.1`. What does your browser say if you do this? `alert(Array.prototype.indexOf);` ? If it alerts a function, my code should work. If not... that's really weird because filter and indexOf were added in the same version of JavaScript.

Comment: `The indexOf() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier.`

Comment: try this if the browser is <IE 9.         if(!Array.indexOf){
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
   for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
    if(this[i]==obj){
     return i;
    }
   }
   return -1;
  }
}

Comment: Ah... then why is `.filter()` supported? Weird. I updated my answer for the asker, for IE8 and earlier.

Comment: Did you test this on a page with any libraries?  That might have been why - I'm pretty sure that IE8 doesn't have `.filter()` natively.

Answer (score 1):

you can use directly to remove duplicates from array1 as

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var arr1=["a","b","b","c","c","d"];
     var arr2=[];   

     $.each(arr1, function(i,el){
            if($.inArray(el, arr2) === -1) 
                arr2.push(el);
           });
      alert(arr2);
   });
```

you can observe here..

http://jsfiddle.net/nPeaV/7410/