# Ensuring Unique Json

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I apologise if this has been asked before but I can't seem to find a solution from other posts on here.

I'm trying to build a json array in local storage (which is fine) but want to check if an entry already exists before adding new values.

The Json itself

```
[{"title":"title1","url":"somefile1.pdf","background":"bg1.png"},
{"title":"title2","url":"somefile2.pdf","background":"bg2.png"},
{"title":"title3","url":"somefile3.pdf","background":"bg3.png"}]
```

Now how would I query the array to ensure only unique entries are being added?

Heres the code to add to array with

```
var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

        var newItem = {
            'title': title,
            'url': url,
            'background': background
        };

        // Need to check the newItem is unique here //

        oldItems.push(newItem);
        localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
```

I thought I could use the jquery unique function instead before setting the localstorage object

```
var cleanedItems = $.unique(oldItems);
localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(cleanedItems));
```

but that didnt work...

Comment: Don't use an array, use an object whose key is whatever property uniquely identifies the elements.

Comment: this might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486479/javascript-array-unique

Comment: Object key comparison is not simple - https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/e4cef1a0833e6d677298600e205a142d15639bf2/lib/assert.js#L205-L247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop over each of the items in the array that is parsed from local storage and perform an object equality test with the new item.

Object equality testing is not as simple as `obj1 == obj2`.

Here are some references to get you started

- http://procbits.com/2012/01/19/comparing-two-javascript-objects
- https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/e4cef1a0833e6d677298600e205a142d15639bf2/lib/assert.js#L205-L247
- http://stamat.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/javascript-object-comparison/
- http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-84

The following may end up working for you, by using `JSON.stringify` to compare the new object as a JSON string with the objects in the old array as JSON strings.

```
function objInArr(newObj, oldItems) {
    var newObjJSON = JSON.stringify(newObj);
    for (var i = 0, l = oldItems.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(oldItems[i]) === newObjJSON) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

var newItem = {
    'title': title,
    'url': url,
    'background': background
};

// Need to check the newItem is unique here
if (!objInArr(newItem, oldItems)) {
    oldItems.push(newItem);
}
localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
```

Comment: absolutely awesome - works exactly as I need and it's much appreciated.. I've been head scratching for a good few hours on this..