# Java scriptlet to remove duplicate in string separated by | (delimiter)

Tags: java, scriptlet

I have a `String` that looks like `"(doc1| doc1| provid| geestt| stable)"`. It represents an array and I want to remove any duplicates from it so that doc1 appears only once. How can I do this?

Comment: In your title you mention that your array is seperated by "|" - do you have a String or an array? Because an array doe snot have a seperation sign

Comment: "How can I do this?" By coding.

Comment: It's a string and the results are separated by a delimiter, i had found something like this  below but it's not working, i tried to change but it doesnt work` var uniqueArray = duplicatesArray.filter(function(elem, pos) {
    return duplicatesArray.indexOf(elem) == pos;
  }); 

`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an array of unique values from an array containing duplicates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486479/how-to-get-an-array-of-unique-values-from-an-array-containing-duplicates-in-java)

Comment: thank you @ Michael i will look at those.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, as the above link asks for a Java solution, not Javascript. I'd rather look at `String.split()` [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String] and `java.util.Set` [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String s = "(doc1|doc1|provid|geestt|provid|stable)";
    s = s.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)\\|(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)", "");
    System.out.println(s);
    // (doc1|geestt|provid|stable)
```

This uses `\\w` for word char; probably you need `[^|)]` that is: not one of the separator chars. The 0-char wide `\\b` is for detecting word boundaries, that fits.

This pattern uses a look-ahead `(?= ... )` containing `\\1` the 1<sup>st</sup> matched `()` group: the word.

P.S.
`Set<String>` seems to be a more appropiate data structure.