# Is there a shortcut for a homemade map and filter function like this in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript

I have these two functions:

```
var map = function(f, xs) {
  return xs.map(f)
}

var filter = function(f, xs) {
  return xs.filter(f)
}
```

With modern browsers is there a shortcut for this functionality?

Comment: How much shorter can it get than `array.map()`?

Comment: `var map = xs.map.bind(xs, f);` ?

Comment: @Bamar - Thanks. The reason I asked is because I earlier posted a question but didn't mention that I was looking for a solution that uses some of the new browser features. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693070/is-there-a-way-i-can-emulate-the-lodash-chain-with-javascript-in-modern-browse  I am sorry but I am not so familiar with JavaScript. Can you put your comment in as an answer and I will be happy to accept that.

Comment: @Barmar it can shorter, like `[].map()`

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski - Can you put that down as an answer and maybe have a look at my other question (link above). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend answer (little shorter) from @Barmar

```
[].map()
```

Instead of creating new global variables like **map** or **filter** please take a look how polyfills can extend missing functionality

- map – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill
- filter – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill