# Vanilla Javascript unique numbers in array with reduce and find

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve to write an array function with the use of reduce and find helpers that returns an array of unique numbers.

```js
var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
// function should return [1, 2, 3, 4]

function unique(array) {
  array.reduce((uniqueArray, number) => {
    if (uniqueArray.indexOf(find(array.number))) {
      uniqueArray.push(array.number);
    }
    return uniqueArray;
  }, []);
}
console.log(unique(numbers));
// undefined 
// undefined
```

When running this code I get

> undefined

twice in Browser Javascript console.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486479/how-to-get-an-array-of-unique-values-from-an-array-containing-duplicates-in-java and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: Unless he MUST use reduce and find - which is the reason I did not hammer close it

Comment: @mplungjan the linked questions doesn't use reduce and find helper.

Comment: Which is why I did not actually close as duplicate

Comment: Why don't you just use map? Could be alot easier imo.

Comment: it's an exercise to get more familiar with reduce

Comment: WTH is `find(array.number)`? Did you mean `array.find(number)`? And why do you pass the result of that to `indexOf`? It seems what you are looking for is `if (uniqueArray.includes(number))`.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, you're right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a return statment.

```
return array.reduce((uniqueArray // ...
// ^^^
```

And some better find method with [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
function unique(array) {
    return array.reduce((uniqueArray, number) => {
        if (uniqueArray.indexOf(number) === -1) {
            uniqueArray.push(number);
        }
        return uniqueArray;
    }, []);
}

var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
console.log(unique(numbers));
```

And now with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for collecting the items in a new array.

```js
function unique(array) {
    return [... new Set(array)];
}

var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
console.log(unique(numbers));
```

Comment: includes is fine, but it does not work in edge, actually.

Comment: your `find` does not work on arrays that contain a `0`. You should use `some` or simply `includes`.

Comment: @Bergi, then indexOf is better, at least as find.

Comment: Yes indeed. An alternative (as long as the array does only contain numbers) is `….find(…) != null`

Comment: @Bergi, if not found, then [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns `undefined`, but if `undefined` is a value, then it does not work.

Comment: That's what I meant by "if the array does only contain numbers" (which `undefined` is not)

Answer (score 3):

The reasons for the errors are explained in previous answers. So I just adding an alternate method with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
// function should return [1, 2, 3, 4]

function unique(array) {
  return array.filter(function(v, i, arr) {
    // compare index with first element index
    return i == arr.indexOf(v);
  })
}
console.log(unique(numbers));
```

---

With ES6 arrow function.

```js
var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
// function should return [1, 2, 3, 4]

function unique(array) {
  return array.filter((v, i, arr) => i == arr.indexOf(v))
}
console.log(unique(numbers));
```

---

**UPDATE :** With a reference object instead of checking the index.

```js
var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
  ref = {};


function unique(array) {
  return array.filter(function(v) {
    if (!(v in ref)) {
      ref[v] = true;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  })
}
console.log(unique(numbers));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have few errors. First you need to return value from your function and also to check if element is already in `uniqueArray` you can use  `indexOf()` == `-1`.

```js
var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];

function unique(array) {
  return array.reduce((uniqueArray, number) => {
    if (uniqueArray.indexOf(number) == -1) uniqueArray.push(number)
    return uniqueArray;
  }, []);
}
console.log(unique(numbers));
```

With ES6/7 you can use `includes()` and arrow functions like this.

```js
var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];

function unique(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((r, n) => (!r.includes(n) ? r.push(n) : 1) && r , []);
}
console.log(unique(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `Array.includes`.

```
function SillyFunctionName(array) {
    "use strict";

    var uniqueArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (uniqueArray.includes(array[i])) {
            break;
        } else {
            uniqueArray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

    return uniqueArray;
}
```