# how to create a unique filter filter component in angular2

Tags: angular

```
variants: [{"vType":"red"},{"vType":"red"},{"vType":"black"}]
```

I need to use a filter to get unique colors as only "red and black" ill be using

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedVariant" (ngModelChange)="changeVariant(selectedVariant)" >
  <option  *ngFor="let c of selection">{{c.vType}}</option>
</select>
```

how to create a custom filter to filter unique colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build custom filter you can see docs / tuto [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes)

To get your unique collection you could use [lodash _.uniqBy function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy) or make a custom implementation using reduce like ([from this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486479/how-to-get-an-array-of-unique-values-from-an-array-containing-duplicates-in-java))

```
variants = [{"vType":"red"},{"vType":"red"},{"vType":"black"}];
uniqueVariants = variants.reduce(function(accumulatedVariants, variant) {
    if (!accumulatedVariants.find(v => v.vType === variant.vType)) {
          accumulatedVariants.push(c);
    }
    return accumulatedVariants;
}, []);
```

Comment: im not only looking (only) for my rep, but can you validate this answer so your question will no longer be marked as "unanswered", thx